# Elasticsearch - Can I delete a data-stream backing index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a few data-streams configured in my Elasticsearch cluster (with ILM policy).
Suppose I run into storage problems and etc. and I want to prematurely delete a few backing indices of the data-streams- Is it possible?

Currently the backing indices are locked for deleting- is there a way to unlock them and safely delete them?

Answer (score 1):

I not sure, but I think you can delete backing indices :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html#delete-index-api-desc

"You cannot delete the current write index of a data stream. To delete the index, you must roll over the data stream so a new write index is created. You can then use the delete index API to delete the previous write index."